# YoloV3 object detection with tflite model returns around 160 bounding boxes randomly all tagged with first class from the label text

Tags: java, android, tensorflow, object-detection, yolo

The shape of the TFLite model is [1, 2535, 85]. You can find the TFLite model [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17wyP3Vy9RG3EC6gZ5LfaCOQFCZaenwBs/view?usp=sharing) and label text [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1L_Tdb-aggzXEJG1qyjb0e9tbcSlCRnPT/view?usp=sharing).

This is how the bug looks.

[image]

This is the project I used https://github.com/hunglc007/tensorflow-yolov4-tflite/tree/master/android with some few changes. The changes are as following:

1. Added the TFLite model and the text in the assets folder (the label text is already present in the project, its the same).
2. Line 57 DetectorActivity.java.

```
private static final String TF_OD_API_MODEL_FILE = "yolov3-tiny.tflite";
private static final String TF_OD_API_LABELS_FILE = "file:///android_asset/coco.txt";
```

3. line 181 tflite/YoloV4Classifier.java.

```
private static boolean isTiny = true;
```

4. line 426 tflite/YoloV4Classifier.java, (Replace the function to the down below).

This is the code:

```
private ArrayList<Recognition> getDetectionsForTiny(ByteBuffer byteBuffer, Bitmap bitmap) {
    ArrayList<Recognition> detections = new ArrayList<Recognition>();
    Map<Integer, Object> outputMap = new HashMap<>();
    //  outputMap.put(0, new float[1][OUTPUT_WIDTH_TINY[0]][4]);
    outputMap.put(0, new float[1][OUTPUT_WIDTH_TINY[1]][labels.size() + 5]);
    Object[] inputArray = {byteBuffer};
    tfLite.runForMultipleInputsOutputs(inputArray, outputMap);
    int gridWidth = OUTPUT_WIDTH_TINY[0];
    float[][][] bboxes = (float [][][]) outputMap.get(0);
    // float[][][] out_score = (float[][][]) outputMap.get(1);
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < gridWidth; i++) {
        float maxClass = 0;
        int detectedClass = -1;
        final float[] classes = new float[labels.size()];
        for (int c = 0; c < labels.size(); c++) {
            classes [c] = bboxes[0][i][c + 5];
        }
        for (int c = 0; c < labels.size(); ++c) {
            if (classes[c] > maxClass) {
                detectedClass = c;
                maxClass = classes[c];
            }
        }
        final float score = maxClass;
        if (score > getObjThresh()) {
            final float xPos = bboxes[0][i][0];
            final float yPos = bboxes[0][i][1];
            final float w = bboxes[0][i][2];
            final float h = bboxes[0][i][3];
            final RectF rectF = new RectF(
                Math.max(0, xPos - w / 2),
                Math.max(0, yPos - h / 2),
                Math.min(bitmap.getWidth() - 1, xPos + w / 2),
                Math.min(bitmap.getHeight() - 1, yPos + h / 2));
            detections.add(new Recognition("" + i, labels.get(detectedClass), score, rectF, detectedClass));
            count++;
        }
    }
    Log.d("Count", " " + count);
    return detections;
}
```

Please I don't know where I'm going wrong! Struggling with it since days! Thanks for helping.

Comment: Are you applying non max suppression?

Comment: What is wrong with using the original `getDetectionsForTiny` function from the repo?

Comment: Please, can you indicate how does the ```classes``` array looks like when you execute the program? I mean after `for (int c = 0; c < labels.size(); c++) {
            classes [c] = bboxes[0][i][c + 5];
        }`